# Losing sort order converting a List to a Map using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a bit of code that receives a list of objects of a class called `Metric`. The list comes in sorted by name. I am then using the Java Streams API to convert the list to a map, with the name as the key and the value as the `Metric` object.

Metric.java:

```
public class Metric implements Comparable<Metric> {

  private String              name;
  private String              type;
  // ... other fields

  // Getters/Setters removed

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Metric o) {
    if (this.name.equals(o.name)) {
      return this.type.compareTo(o.type);
    }

    return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
  }

}
```

I'm using the following code to perform the list to map conversion:

```
map = allMetrics.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Metric::getName, Function.identity()));
```

I've discovered that the resulting map is no longer ordered by name. I tried adding `sorted()` in front of the `collect()` call, but that had no effect.

I then dug into the `Collectors` class to see if I could figure out what's going on. It turns out the `Collectors.toMap()` methods use a new `HashMap` internally to store the map. I think that's what's messing up the order.

Does anyone know of an alternate way to achieve the list to map conversion and not lose the ordering?

Comment: Maps aren’t ordered at all.